# Объяснить про трансляцию и компиляцию

Tags: любой-язык

Языки делятся на интерпретируемые и компилируемые. А в чем суть отличия? Команды же все равно переводятся в битовые инструкции? Нужно ли вообще так глубоко копать для веб-разработчика?

Comment: Компилятор в машинный код например команду сложения превратит в единственную инструкцию, которая выполнится за один такт. А интерпретатор видя ее в дереве выполнения вызовет какую нибудь свою функцию, которая подкелает кучу разных операций за несколько сотен тактов, т.е. в сотни раз медленнее

Comment: @Mike а теперь добавляем JIT :)

Comment: @andreymal поэтому я уточнил что в машинный код, а то сейчас диссертацию на тему компиляторов в качестве ответа придется написать :) Которая при этом ничего не разъяснит, раз википедия не помогает

Comment: Трансляция - на сколько я знаю такого термина нет, могу ошибаться, знаю что есть транспиляция - перевод из одного языка в другой, например из TypeScript в JavaScript. Что касается интерпритации и компиляции, то для быстрой разработки и экспериментов удобны именно интерпретируемые языки, поэтому Python и JavaScript популярные языки, но благодаря своей гибкости они уступают по производительности. Плюсы компилируемых языков в основном в скорости работы а не разработки и тестировании.

Comment: Вопрос на тему, что такое "куча", вернее, сколько зерен ее составляют...

Comment: Нет конечно. Веб-разработчик не программист же))) Ему вообще ничего не нужно значть об устройстве компа. А если серьезно, то в Википедии все было написано вполне понятно. Интерпретация - это "компиляция на лету". Кстати, некоторые интерпретируемые языки можно и скомпилировать, но, естественно, под конкретную платформу. Очевидно, что скомпилированный код быстрее, а интерпретируемый - переносимее. А есть нечто среднее - код "скомпилированный" для виртуальной машины (байт код).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***В компилируемых языках*** (С, С++, Go, etc) код предварительно проверяется на ошибки и потом переводится в инструкции процессора и в дальнейшем при запуске им не нужно дополнительное программное обеспечение.

***В интерпретируемых языках*** (JavaScript, Python, Lisp, etc) используется промежуточное ПО, которое читает код прямо из файла и выполняет его, без перевода в инструкции процессора. Без интерпретатора невозможно запустить программу и из-за разбора кода на лету они работают медленнее (тоже относительное понятие, для большинства задач хватает скорости).

Есть **языки с промежуточной компиляцией в байт код** (Java, C#, CPython, etc), которые выполняются так же с помощью промежуточного ПО, но по скорости могут не уступать компилируемым языкам. В этом случае код компилируется не напрямую в инструкции процессора, а в промежуточный байт-код.

При изучении языка и вообще программирования вы столкнетесь с этими терминами, но копать заранее не имеет особого смысла, разве что для общего развития и представления.

***Трансляция*** - перевод из одного языка в другой язык, немного из другой темы.

Comment: *Трансляция - перевод из одного языка в другой язык*, например, в машинные коды :)

Comment: @Harry совершенно верно, как один из вариантов трансляции, но приходится соблюдать формальности :-) Вот избегают говорить трансляция при обсуждении этой темы, да еще и подозрительно смотрят, когда не используешь специальное слово компиляция.

Comment: Вообще, всем нужно доп. ПО -- ОС =) (если вы только не написали оную)

Comment: @megorit спорное утверждение, чтобы запускать программы компилируемых языков ОС не нужна. То, что вы пользуетесь услугами ОС и стороннего ПО, это уже личный выбор разработчика т.к. это проще, быстрее, удобнее. Простейший пример Arduino - скомпилированная программа и голое железо без всяких ОС.

Comment: Любая софтина завязана на ABI и API ОС. Это не выбор, кстати)) Без ОС никуда.

Comment: Относительно Lisp это не совсем правильно. У различных диалектов есть разные решения, но например в Common Lisp, самом развитом диалекте, есть интерактивная командная строка вместе с мощным компилятором, который на лету компилирует выражения. Другими словами, Common Lisp есть в равной степени интерактивный и компилируемый.

Comment: @WojciechGac, если мы начнем говорить про относительности, то я должен буду удалить свой ответ т.к. на любой язык можно сделать интерпретатор, компилятор или промежуточную компиляцию. И более того, они сделаны и существуют. Поэтому давайте остановимся на механизме выполнения, а не на частностях и конкретных реализациях.

Comment: @AlexKrass Я согласен. Просто, это мой "коленный рефлекс" когда я вижу некие обычные понятия по теме Лиспа, которые новички могут интерпретировать как недостатки :).